# open uploaded json file

Tags: php, json, upload

Im trying to finish a upload tool which can open a json file and show it in a table. The script i posted below (basis.php) is already working properly.

**basis.php**

```
$data = file_get_contents("data.json"); // put the contents of the file into a variable

$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pure-min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<table class="pure-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tijdstempel</th>
            <th>Voornaam</th>
            <th >NHL E-mailadres</th>
            <th>Geboortejaar</th>
            <th>Kwaliteit</th>
            <th>Moeilijkheidsniveau</th>
            <th>Gegevenscontrole</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>
    <tbody>   
        <tr >
            <td> <?php echo $character->Tijdstempel; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Voornaam; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Email; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Geboortejaar; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Kwaliteit; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Moeilijkheidsniveau; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Gegevenscontrole; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here comes the problem, I am trying to change the basis.php and adapt it to the following index.php. This way I want to be able to upload a suitable json file instead.

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Basisformulier voor het uploaden van een bestand</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Excel bestanden importeren en exporteren</h1>

    <form action="basis.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="frm_importfile">Selecteer het bestand:</label>

        <input type="file" name="importfile" id="frm_importfile">
        <button type="submit">Upload het bestand</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

So I tryed to change the basis.php in this way:

**basis.php(not working)**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_FILES['importfile'])){
        echo "FOUT: Je hebt geen bestand geselecteerd om te uploaden";
        exit;
    }

$data = fopen($_FILES['importfile']['tmp_name'], "r");


$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pure-min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<table class="pure-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tijdstempel</th>
            <th>Voornaam</th>
            <th >NHL E-mailadres</th>
            <th>Geboortejaar</th>
            <th>Kwaliteit</th>
            <th>Moeilijkheidsniveau</th>
            <th>Gegevenscontrole</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>
    <tbody>   
        <tr >
            <td> <?php echo $character->Tijdstempel; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Voornaam; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Email; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Geboortejaar; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Kwaliteit; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Moeilijkheidsniveau; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $character->Gegevenscontrole; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been searching for solutions for a long while on the internet but I still cant get the problem solved. I hope that someone can help me and show me how I can make it possible to upload a json file to the basis.php.

Kind Regards,

Sierra

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working?

Comment: Well the script is able to read scv files in this way but when i adapt it to read json files it fails and gives the following errors om Fifefox:


Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php programmeren 2017\nieuwe opzet\phptest\basis.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php programmeren 2017\nieuwe opzet\phptest\basis.php on line 32

Answer (score 1):

You open the file but you didn't read any data from it.
A simple method to get the contents of a file is `file_get_contents`

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['importfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It sounds stupid but i was stuck with this for 2 days making no progression and now it works! Only the error line which is in Dutch language doesnt reveal when nothing is uploaded

Comment: if(!isset($_FILES['importfile']['name']))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but adding the ['name'] ore ['tmp_name'] doesnt change the error:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\php programmeren 2017\nieuwe opzet\phptest\basis.php on line 7

Comment: do a dump of `$_FILES` to see what's in it

Comment: Yes thank you for telling me about the dump option. It worked: $_FILES['name']

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['importfile']['tmp_name']);

Comment: Thanks for your response same as Musa